# Do I need to set different coordinates for an iphone 4/ 5 game?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, sprite-kit

first of all I'm a noob game developer. I've been testing my game on iOs simulator with iphone retina 4 inch, and since months everything were more or less ok. Today I've purchased my license and tested in my iphone 4 and the first screen is what I get (taken from iOs simulator iphone 3,5 inch) but what I need to get is in the second screen (iphone 4 inch-iOs simulator):

[image: This is with iphone 4/4s]

[image: This is iphone 5 (OK)]
My question is, do I need to set up coordinates two times for each devices? how can I fix this?
I've already tried to replace the `viewDidLoad()` method for `viewWillLayoutSubviews` but it shows everything too little and the background don't fit, there's a lot of black screen, it's only ok to have a general view of everything but don't show the game like in the second screen.

Answer (score 0):

First You check to make sure what device it is by doing the following:

```
if ((int)[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568)
{
    //  iPhone 5 screen, load iP5 coords here
} else {
    //  iPhone 4 screen, load iP4 coords here
}
```